# Deploying to a clustered weblogic application server or Red Hat Linux

Tags: weblogic

I am developing an application with following software stack:

1. XHTML / CSS / ExtJS / DWR / Javascript (Presentation Layer)
2. EJB 3.0 / Spring MVC
3. Hibernate / Hibernate Spatial

My application works well in a single server development environment. But deploying to clustered weblogic environment on Red Hat does not work and results in the following exception:

============================================================================================

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.xs.XSSimpleTypeDecl.applyFacets(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.xs.XSSimpleTypeDecl.applyFacets1(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.xs.BaseSchemaDVFactory.createBuiltInTypes(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.xs.SchemaDVFactoryImpl.createBuiltInTypes(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.xs.SchemaDVFactoryImpl.(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.ObjectFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.SchemaDVFactory.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.SchemaDVFactory.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.SchemaGrammar$BuiltinSchemaGrammar.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.SchemaGrammar.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.configurePipeline(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration.configurePipeline(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:280)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:101)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:390)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:327)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:244)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:50)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1801)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3042)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1374)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:455)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:205)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:60)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:201)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:118)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:205)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:60)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:28)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:630)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:206)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:53)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:184)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:361)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:52)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:196)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:31)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:233)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:170)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:124)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:174)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:90)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)

============================================================================================

My initial thought is that there is a clash in the Xerces library being used. But I could use any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try manually adding the versions of xbeans.jar and xerces.jar to the beginning of your classpath so that the ones included in WebLogic's installation get overridden?

Answer (score 0):

Common answer is rename correct version of xerces.jar to _xerces.jar to put this library to begin of CLASSPATH